# How to solve the differential equation $\frac{dy}{ dx} =\frac{1}{x\cos{y}-\sin{2y}}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have tried different methods for solving the following differential equation, but I could not solve it.
$$\frac{dy}{ dx} =\frac{1}{x\cos{y}-\sin{2y}}$$

Comment: what actually is the question? are you attempting to find the original function? any turning points? and i assume this is implicitly defined?

Comment: HINT $ \sin 2x= 2 \sin x \cos x $ Variables are separable. $ \int \dfrac{dx}{2 \sin x -x} $

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac1{x \cos y - \sin 2y} \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac1{\cos y} \cdot\frac1{x- 2\sin y} \\
\end{align}$$
Now use the substitution $u = \sin y$ to give $\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx} \cos y$, and so
$$\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} \cos y &= \frac1{x- 2\sin y} \\
\frac{du}{dx} &= \frac1{x-2u} \\
\frac{dx}{du} &= x-2u\\
\end{align}$$
This is a linear differential equation, which you should be able to solve for.  Then you can simply substitute back in $y$ for $u$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint : $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x\cos y-\sin 2y}$$
 $$\implies \frac{dx}{dy}=x\cos y-\sin 2y$$
Do you remember the linear differential equation. Think of $x=f(y)$.

The solution to the equation $$\frac{dx}{dy}+P(y) \cdot x =Q(y)$$ Will be

$$x \cdot e^{\int P(y) \mathrm dy}=\int e^{\int P(y) \mathrm dy} \cdot Q(y) \mathrm dy$$

Comment: @imranfat Thanks a lot!